# Where can I put an uploading folder so that when I deploy/undeploy the site in Tomcat that folder won't be affected

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I've made a site in JSP (online shop). An user has logged in and uploaded some photos with a control panel that i've made. I want now to make some modifications to that site, but if I undeploy it ... Tomcat will delete the photos.

How can I download the site or photos folder?
Where can I put photos folder so that when I deploy/undeploy the site, photos folder won't be affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a properties file, in there

[Windows]

```
archive_folder=c:\archive\
```

Or

[Linux]

```
archive_folder = /opt/archive/
```

Read the folder path from that properties file and store your photos there. Since the folder is located outside of the application, it won't get deleted.

Comment: and if i want to refer to one file named "a.gif" from that folder ?
<a href="?"> click </a> (I'm a beginner. Sorry)

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/361103/Servlets/java/download-file-server-through-servlet  . I hope it helped