# Where do I put application generated HTML reports to that they don't get removed when I deploy a new WAR file?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I have a simple web application which lets the user upload local user data and then they can generate HTML reports from that uploaded data.  Once the HTML is generated, I display a link to the report which they can click on to view in their browser or they can share the link with others.

The problem is that I am currently putting the "/Upload" folder in the "WEB-INF" folder because I don't want that folder data accessible to the outside world.  I am then putting the "Reports" folder in the root directory of the web application.  This work fine in that I can deploy the WAR file to the their server, the user can upload the files, and then request for HTML reports to be generated.  The problem is that when I send them software updates in the WAR file it deletes everyone in the /MyWebApp directory including the /Upload and /Reports folder.  So then the user has to re-upload the data and they loose any of their existing reports in the "/Reports" folder.

Now I did find an answer for the /Upload folder on StackOverflow with this discussion.
[Where can I put an uploading folder so that when I deploy/undeploy the site in Tomcat that folder won't be affected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937758/where-can-i-put-an-uploading-folder-so-that-when-i-deploy-undeploy-the-site-in-t)

But I still don't know where to put my "/Reports" folder?  I thought I would have to put it in the web application context directory as I am doing now in order for the Tomcat server to serve it up as a link (e.g.: http://example.com/MyWebApp/Reports/report01.html).

The other thing to note is that this application is running on Apache Tomcat only, I don't have the request going through an Apache server.  We decided to just have it running on the users local server with Tomcat because it seems easier to deploy then trying to deploy and configure both to work together.  Also, there are only 2-3 people using this application per server site and with that load Tomcat seems to be doing a great job handling everything on its own. So maybe that is making the solution more difficult?

Any hep with best practices for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ended up creating another web context to hold the application generated data in. That way the reports can be served from it and when I deploy a new WAR file to update my application it will not wipe out what is in this new context.  That seems to be working for now, though once we move to Tomcat 7 I think the answer provided by @christopher-schultz (see below) will be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no difference between the strategy you used for placing uploaded-files on the disk with placing reports on the disk: both are files that were generated by the webapp during its deployment (forget the fact that a client uploaded the file) and need to be protected in the same way.

If you are willing to upgrade to Tomcat 7, there is a new `<Context>` attribute, `aliases`, which will allow your webapp to serve content from that directory but not delete it when the webapp is undeployed.

Comment: It looks like the new '<Context>' attribute 'aliases' in Tomcat 7 would work, unfortunately we can not move to Tomcat 7 yet.
The problem with the strategy I have for the "/Upload" folder that I don't think would work for the "/Reports" folder is that I want to be able to provide a link to the generated reports.  So where my serlvet can access data any where on the server, I do not think Tomcat can serve stuff outside of context with out some sort of configuration which is what I am trying to figure out. What did people do before Tomcat 7?

Comment: How do you serve the uploaded files? Or, do you not serve those at all? In either case, you could write a servlet that maps a URL space on the disk -- much like the DefaultServlet does. Remember, your code is free to read files from wherever it wants (barring file permissions and the presence of a SecurityManager).

Comment: No, I don't serve the uploaded files I just need to make sure they don't get wiped out every time I push a new WAR file.  Otherwise the user has to re-upload them every time.  Now I do serve the reports.  I ended up adding a new context to serve the reports.  Like you said my application can write to where ever it wants.  So, I write the reports to that new context and then just provide a link to http://example.com/MyWebReports/Reports/report01.html instead of http://example.com/MyWebApp/Reports/report01.html
Once we move to Tomcat 7, I will use the "aliases" as you suggested.

Comment: Don't forget that those reports will be blown-away if you undeploy `MyWebReports`.